# PDF versions supported by PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

I've been looking for all the PDF versions that are supported by Apache PDFBOX. I'm using PDFBOx 0.7.3 version and actually i'm able to process all PDF's from 1.5 and older but i need to process newer versions (1.6, 1.7 and so on). Do you know if upgrading PDFBOX could solve this issue? also is there any  guide to upgrade PDFBOX? if so could you provide it? Which version do you recommend?

Comment: What specific features of 1.6 and 1.7 do you need?

Comment: I wonder the same as @TilmanHausherr. Furthermore, though, you should consider updating, version *0.7.3* is old, 1.8.x is current stable, 2.0.0 is under development now.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for response, actually i decided upgrade the PDFBox to 1.8.8, i think is the latest stable, and it works, I'm now able to parse the PDF1.5 and newer.

Thanks.