# PDFBox text extraction - empty output

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract some infos from a set of PDFs. This works so far, but one PDF gives me grievances.

I'm using PDFBox 1.8.8, with Java 7.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
System.out.println("File: "+pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()+" readable: "+pdfFile.canRead()+" size: "+pdfFile.length());
System.out.println(stripper.getText(document));
```

It just prints

```
File: /foo/bar/mypdf.pdf readable: true size: 1267743
```

Then it terminates. Usually I use the writeText method and funnel the text through a stream, but above code was used for simplification. I've tried converting the PDF with `pdftotext` - it works just like the others.

I get no exception, no nothing. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Additional Info: Created with Acrobat Distiller 9.0.0 (Windows), Format PDF-1.6; The other PDFs are Version 1.4 and 1.5

Doesn't seem to contain exotic characters. I can mark/copy text in Evince PDF-viewer

EDIT2:

Dang it. File property dialog (Nautilus) said "Security: No", but `pdfinfo` gives me:

```
Encrypted:      yes (print:yes copy:no change:no addNotes:no algorithm:AES)
```

Anyway to circumvent that? After all, `pdftotext` could get the text out.

Comment: Can you share the PDF to reproduce the issue? And... *Then it terminates* - have you tried enclosing `System.out.println(stripper.getText(document));` in `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }`?

Comment: PdfBox sometimes fails if the pdf contains non-Latin characters. Is it the case ??

Comment: @mkl I'm afraid I can't :( It's work related. It terminates, bc. I put a System.exit(1) after the code above. But it should print something first. Did try the catch-all, but nothing.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati it doesn't, as far as I've seen. But I just checked and saw, that it's the only PDF in the 1.6 Format. The others are 1.4, 1.5. Does PDFbox support that? Can't find anything.

Comment: PDFBox1.8.8 works for PDF v1.6 [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573893/4333131). There must be some other cases.

Comment: I'm afraid that without the PDF in question I have no further idea.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is actually text in the PDF document? Can you copy and paste it with Acrobat or something similar for example?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche the OP in his question said "I can mark/copy text in Evince PDF-viewer"

Comment: Thank you all for your help. So it seems like there is some kind of copy protection/encryption on it...

Comment: *copy protection/encryption* - not necessarily. Might also be a PDFBox issue. You might want to test using the current development version 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT which contains numerous improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document was "encrypted" (write protected), but with no user password set. This Stackoverflow answer shows how you can remove the encryption and simply read the file: [remove encryption from pdf with pdfbox, like qpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700241/remove-encryption-from-pdf-with-pdfbox-like-qpdf/14700523#14700523)